# sharepoint rest services - executeAsync not working

Tags: jquery, rest, web-parts, sharepoint-2013, splistitem

I'm using Sharepoint Rest services to update List Items. To do the update, I'm using the function executeAsync from the SP.RequestExecutor object. The code was working fine, but while I was testing it today, I realized the ListItems weren't updating and the executeAsync function was working fine ( going to the success function and there were no errors).

```
function ActualizarDatosListaConItemType(urlSitio, nomlista, id, metadata, funcionExito, funcionError,     itemType, esAsync) {
// Prepping our update
var item = $.extend({ "__metadata": { "type": itemType } }, metadata);
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(urlSitio);
executor.executeAsync({
                        url: urlSitio + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + nomlista + "')/items('" + id + "')",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        data: JSON.stringify(item),                           
                        headers: {
                                  "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                                  "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                                  "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                                  "If-Match": "*"
                                  },
  success: function (data) { funcionExito(data); },
  error: function (data) { funcionError(data); }
 });
}
```

My code is fine I think, please help T_T.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been futzing around with this for a few days and my finding is the SP.RequestExecutor has slightly different parameter names than the normal 'direct' ajax query.

For example, instead of

```
type: "POST"
```

use

```
method: "POST"
```

and for the actual data package to post, instead of

```
data: JSON.stringify(item)
```

use

```
body: JSON.stringify(item)
```

finally, while the GetByTitle embedded function uses quotes for the title parameter within the parenthesis, the items does not. So instead of

.../items('123')

use

.../items(123)

For completeness, here is the block that I used to update via rest using javascript across a domain with the SP.RequestExecutor object:

```
    new SP.RequestExecutor(closureThis.appweburl).executeAsync(
        {
            url: closureThis.appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists(guid\'" + listIdGuid + "\')/items(" + itemId + ")?@target='" + closureThis.hostweburl + "'",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": closureThis.getDigestValue(),
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                "If-Match": "*"
            },
            body: updateBlock,
            success: function (data) { closureThis.updateDataObjectCallback(data); },
            error: spRequestorErrorHandler
        }
    );
```

Where closureThis is an object I use to store SharePoint variables and handle callbacks
Where updateBlock is the JSON.stringify(data) value

My updateBlock value looks like this:

"{\"__metadata\":{\"type\":\"SP.Data.TasksListItem\"},\"Title\":\"First Task\"}"

Comment: I'm gonna take this one as the answer. The problem wasn't exactly mine, it was a friend's. He said that the execute method started to work magically again so...w/e